# Select points by identify() in multiple plots

Tags: r, identify

I have a data frame `df`, each of its columns is plotted as a simple scatter plot. I want to select a single point in each graph by `identify()` and store it in a list `s` - one graph after another. Here is my approach:

```
x1 <- c(12:4, 5:8, NA, NA)
x2 <- c(15:8, 9:15)
df <- data.frame(x1, x2)

fun <- function(z){
    y <- na.omit(z)
    x <- seq(1:length(y))
    plot(x,y)
    s <- identify(x, n = 1, plot = F)
}

lapply(df, fun)
```

I'm getting the following error after selecting a point in the first graph:

```
> warning: no point within 0.25 inches
```

But it seems that the point in the second plot is detected properly.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There seems to be an open issue regarding this. No answer yet. I'm finding the same behavior: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3162

Comment: They say it's working in `RGui`, so that could be an interim fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add one more argument to `identify`, so it knows which y-coordinates to look for.

```
s <- identify(x = x, y = y, n = 1, plot = F)
```

After changing this, your function worked fine for me.